# Regex pattern to match +/-

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I need a Regex pattern to match all 3 possible combinations.

-1

+1

+/-1

With this pattern `(?<margin>(?:\+|-))?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?` I am able to match first and second combination. What must be added to include the third combination too?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Try `(?<margin>(?:\+(?:\/-)?|-))?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?`

Comment: @Yunnosch, I only posted what I was missing to achieve and I tried something like (?:[+][/][-](?<margin>\d+(?:\.\d+)?))? but it was not working. The number could be anything from 1 to n.

Comment: Try this: `(?<margin>\+/-|[+-])(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way (which I believe is the shortest):

```
(?<margin>\+/-|[+-])(\d+(\.\d+)?)
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/wK7qRqLQSfdDQN).